# apps crashes when listview item is clicked

Tags: android, contacts

I'm working on application which is showing all contacts of in list view, now i want to edit the contacts, i wrote code on setOnItemClickListener event so that i will get contact details. i have written following code.My application is crashing whenever i clicked on listview item please help me.Please guide me what to do to update contact detail.If i am moving in wrong direction please guide me.

code:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 
        lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
        TVContactText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.contactEntryText);
        btnAddContact=(Button)findViewById(R.id.addContactButton);

        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

        cur=getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        int a=cur.getCount();
        if(cur.moveToFirst())
        {
        do{
            int nameidx=cur.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME);
                int Ididx=cur.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.NUMBER);
            String strName=cur.getString(nameidx);
            names.add(strName);                 
           }while(cur.moveToNext());

        cur.close();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_view_item_new, R.id.contactEntryText,names);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter); 
        registerForContextMenu(lv);
        } 
       btnAddContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
       {
           public void onClick(View v)
          {
              launchContactAdder();
            }
       });
          //i want to get info regarding contact..
       lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
       {          
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {           
            ContactAt(position);  

         }   
        }); 

    }
```

but my application is crashing whenever i clicked on listview item please help me.

Comment: can you show us what log says?

Comment: Obviously it crashes in *ContactAt()*. Sorry for repeating this, you seriously need to take a diversion and pick up a book on java and android programming.

Comment: Can you show the ContactAt method? (btw note that this method name does not follow the java naming conventions)

Comment: @ bhups :03-09 11:49:00.111: WARN/ActivityManager(68): Force finishing activity com.test.contact/.contacttest Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{44028c60 com.test.contact/.contacttest} i getting these logs but i am not getting anything from these logs as i m new to android. :-(

Comment: I always ask myself why people are asking questions with missing information but when asked about it they just don't answer anymore.

Comment: @Roflcoptr: as i am new to android that function i used only for testing nothing any important i am doing in that but if my above code work then i will go further.. but for your reference my code for function is:

Comment: @Neha Obviously your code is failing right there so I do think it is important

Comment: @Roflcoptr,@Khotmanish: my fun is-protected void ContactAt(int position) { Toast.makeText(this,"hi ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); } nw when i click on list its showing me msg hi but new i need contact id to update or show info please guide me what to do next. thanks to all for responding so quick

Comment: @Neha So the application does not crash?

Comment: @ Roflcoptr: ya now its not crashing but still i dnt know the reason why it was and what is solution for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an explanation how to use ArrayAdapter:

http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/using-arrayadapter-and-listview-in-android-applications

As you can see, you can use getItem(position) to retrieve the element on which the click event was registered.

Comment: hi actually again my application is crashing but this time my code and everything is right.actually before installing on device i tried it on emulator it was runing after that i made clean build and then again build it after that this is 2nd day my application is not runing it is crashing pls guide me.

Comment: @Neha. And now it is really crashing or just not doing what you want? When it is crashing, then again: post your log!

Comment: Actually when i click on specific contact its not doing any thing may because of that it crashes.so to write furture i wanted to know how to show the details of selected contact is there any native api so that i can call the in build contact edit activity, please guide me.

Comment: @Neha I can just repeat my ansewr. When the app is crashing we need the logcat to find out where the error is.